# tail probability of multivariate normal distribution

Tags: probability

What is closed form equation for the tail probability of multivariate normal distribution ?

**y** ~ $\mathcal{N}$($0$, $\sigma^2I_n$ ) ; **y** $\in\mathbb{R}^n$

Pr(**y** > $\gamma$) = $\int_\gamma^\infty$ pr(**y**) d **y** ; $\gamma\in\mathbb{R}$

-Sun

Comment: You could ask yourself where your $\gamma$ lives? Is it in $\mathbb{R}$ (as the appearance of $\gamma$ as a bound of the integral seems to indicate) or in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (as the expression $\mathbb{y}>\gamma$ suggests)? This cannot be both...

Comment: scope of $\gamma$ added...

Comment: Then what does $\mathbb{y}>\gamma$ means? You cannot have it both ways.

Comment: It might mean that each component of $\mathbf{y}$ is bigger than $\gamma$. That would make sense.

Comment: @Raskolnikov Sure, it *might*... Then one wonders about the one-dimensional integral on the RHS. My point is that the OP should make the question clearer.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to make sense of this problem: rectangular and radial.

The rectangular approach is to make $\gamma$ a vector and interpret $y > \gamma$ to mean that every component of $y$ is greater than the corresponding component of $\gamma$. This is a common problem, but it cannot be solved in closed form. See [this article](http://www.math.wsu.edu/faculty/genz/papers/mvn/mvn.html) for numerical algorithms.

The radial approach is to ask for the probability that $|y| > \gamma$, i.e. the probability that $y$ is further than a distance $\gamma$ from the origin. That's an easier problem.

Answer (score 1):

One way to define "tail probability" is by using the notion of *rarity*. Suppose an outcome has probability $p$ under some distribution $\mathcal{D}$. Its *rarity* is
$$\Pr[\Pr[\mathcal{D}] \leq p].$$
So the rarity is the probability that the outcome of $\mathcal{D}$ is as rare as your particular outcome. In the case of a $N(0,1)$, for example, the rarity of an outcome $x$ is equal to the total weight of both tails extending from $ \pm |x|$ outwards.

The nice thing is that the rarity of a random outcome of $\mathcal{D}$ (if it is continuous) is uniformly distributed (exercise). So it converts an arbitrary continuous random distribution to a uniform scale.

Given a multivariate normal distribution $N(\mu,\Sigma)$, we see that the probability of $x$ depends only on $(x-\mu)'\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)$. In the case where $\mu=0$ and $\Sigma=I$, we simply get $x'x$, which is a sum of squares. In the general case, there is an affine transformation which yields a $N(0,I)$ variable. We are thus led to the [chi-square distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-square_distribution).

The [chi-square goodness-of-fit test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-square_test), for example, starts with a multinomial distribution, approximates it using a multivariate distribution, and then outputs the rarity metric, which is chi-square distributed.